# Why value inside an Array within a function( ) within an addEventListener not following my if?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I want to create infinite object slider, which array 0 will go back to 24. There will be 25 picture that moving and changing shape when a left or right button clicked.

Why, array of 14 is numbArr[2]; number will reduce to minus and so on. meanwhile, inside function, 14 is i, number will stay 24 forever.

edit. (sorry if I use confusing variables name, to make it easy to understand:

- let eleven = is counter for eleven post (second left from middle)
- let twelve = is counter for twelve post (left from middle)
- let thirteen = is counter for thirteen post (middle)
- let fourteen = is counter for fourteen post (right from middle)
- let fifteen = is counter for fifteen post (second right from middle)

).

[Example of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7CQX.jpg)

```js
// 
// Infinite Slider Button
// 

const slrdBtnBefore = document.getElementById(`sldr-btn-before`);
const sldrBtnAfter = document.getElementById(`sldr-btn-after`);

// 
// Infinite Slider classList
// 

const bbleCont = [`one-cont`, `two-cont`, `three-cont`, `four-cont`, `five-cont`, `six-cont`, `seven-cont`, `eight-cont`, `nine-cont`, `ten-cont`, `eleven-cont`, `twelve-cont`, `thirteen-cont`, `fourteen-cont`, `fifteen-cont`, `sixteen-cont`, `seventeen-cont`, `eighteen-cont`, `nineteen-cont`, `twenty-cont`, `twentyone-cont`, `twentytwo-cont`, `twentythree-cont`, `twentyfour-cont`, `twentyfive-cont`];
// console.log(bbleCont);

const bbleNumb = [`bble-one`, `bble-two`, `bble-three`, `bble-four`, `bble-five`, `bble-six`, `bble-seven`, `bble-eight`, `bble-nine`, `bble-ten`, `bble-eleven`, `bble-twelve`, `bble-thirteen`, `bble-fourteen`, `bble-fifteen`, `bble-sixteen`, `bble-seventeen`, `bble-eighteen`, `bble-nineteen`, `bble-twenty`, `bble-twentyone`, `bble-twentytwo`, `bble-twentythree`, `bble-twentyfour`, `bble-twentyfive`];
// console.log(bbleNumb);

// 
// Infinite Slider Variable
// 

const contS = document.querySelectorAll(`.bble-cont`);
//console.log(contS.length);
const bubbS = document.querySelectorAll(`.bble-basic`);
// console.log(bubbS);

// 
// Number (Important!)
// 

let twelve = 11;
let thirteen = 12;
let fourteen = 13;

// 
// addEventListener
// 

slrdBtnBefore.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  fourteen--;

  const numbArr = [twelve, thirteen, fourteen];
  console.log(`array of 14 is `, numbArr[2]);

  function exeC(numb, index, filter, keyword) {
    const e = contS[index];
    const f = bubbS[index];
    const g = numb - 1;
    const h = numb + 1;
    let i = numbArr[keyword];

    if (i < 0) {
      i = contS.length - 1;
    } else if (i > contS.length - 1) {
      i = 0;
    }

    console.log(numb);
    console.log(`inside function, 14 is `, i);
    e.classList.add(bbleCont[i]);
    f.classList.add(bbleNumb[i]);

    if (filter == 1) {
      e.classList.remove(bbleCont[h]);
      f.classList.remove(bbleNumb[h]);
    } else {
      e.classList.remove(bbleCont[g]);
      f.classList.remove(bbleNumb[g]);
    }
  }

  exeC(fourteen, 13, 1, 2);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

:root {
  --test-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  --main-font: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(./assets/csgo-wallpaper.png) center/cover fixed no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* 
Header
*/

header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.h-container {
  /* background: red; */
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* 
Page Startup
Animation
*/

.h-load {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  z-index: 5;
}

.trigger-one {
  /* transition: all 1.5s ease-out 1.5s; */
  background: transparent;
}

.h-load-bble {
  padding: 4.5rem;
  height: 750px;
  width: 750px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.trigger-two {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  /* transition: all 1.5s ease-out 1.5s, border-radius 0s; */
  padding: 4.5rem;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border-top: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 4.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -10px 15px 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), -20px 30px 20px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), -30px 50px 30px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.trigger-three {
  display: none;
}

/* 
Infinte Slider
Teams
*/

.h-sldr {
  /* background: red; */
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
}

/* 
Infinter Slider
Button
*/

.sldr-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border: transparent;
  width: 4vw;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sldr-btn i {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 7.5rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}

.sldr-btn i:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

/* 
Infinite Slider
Track
*/

.sldr-track {
  /* background: var(--test-background); */
  height: 75vh;
  width: 92vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

/*
Infinite Slider
Teams
*/

.bble-cont {
  /* background: red; */
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.bble-basic {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  /* background: red; */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.one-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-one {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.two-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-two {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.three-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: -5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-three {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.four-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: -5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-four {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.five-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-five {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.six-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 3.25%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.bble-six {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.seven-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
}

.bble-seven {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.eight-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 7.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bble-eight {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 135px;
  width: 135px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.nine-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
}

.bble-nine {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.ten-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 15.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
}

.bble-ten {
  padding: 3rem;
  height: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.eleven-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 24%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
}

.bble-eleven {
  padding: 3.5rem;
  height: 275px;
  width: 275px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twelve-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

.bble-twelve {
  padding: 4.5rem;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.thirteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bble-thirteen {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  padding: 5rem;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  box-shadow: -10px 15px 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), -20px 30px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25), -30px 50px 30px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-top: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 4.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.bble-thirteen:hover {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: skewX(0deg);
  box-shadow: none;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
}

.fourteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 65%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

.bble-fourteen {
  padding: 4.5rem;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.fifteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 76%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
}

.bble-fifteen {
  padding: 4.5rem;
  height: 275px;
  width: 275px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.sixteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 84.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
}

.bble-sixteen {
  padding: 3rem;
  height: 225px;
  width: 225px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.seventeen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
}

.bble-seventeen {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.eighteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 92.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.bble-eighteen {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 135px;
  width: 135px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.nineteen-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 95%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
}

.bble-nineteen {
  padding: 2.25rem;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twenty-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 96.75%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.bble-twenty {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twentyone-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-twentyone {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twentytwo-cont {
  top: 50%;
  left: 105%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-twentytwo {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twentythree-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: 105%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-twentythree {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twentyfour-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-twentyfour {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.twentyfive-cont {
  top: -15%;
  left: 65%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bble-twentyfive {
  padding: 1.75rem;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>PGL Major Stockholm 2021</title>

  <!-- Website Logo -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/PGL-Major.png" type="image/x-icon">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <!-- Main CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <div class="h-container">
      <div id="load-bckgrnd" class="h-load  trigger-three">
        <div id="load-objct" class="h-load-bble">
          <img src="./assets/PGL-Major.png" alt="PGL Stockhom Major 2021.png">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="h-sldr">
        <button id="sldr-btn-before" class="sldr-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="sldr-track">

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont one-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-one">
              <img src="./assets/Mouz.png" alt="MOUZ.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont two-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-two">
              <img src="./assets/Team-Liquid.png" alt="Team Liquid.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont three-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-three">
              <img src="./assets/Evil-Geniuses.png" alt="Evil Geniuses.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont four-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-four">
              <img src="./assets/ENCE.png" alt="ENCE.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont five-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-five">
              <img src="./assets/BIG.png" alt="BIG.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont six-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-six">
              <img src="./assets/Team-Spirit.png" alt="Team Spirit.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont seven-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-seven">
              <img src="./assets/Movistar-Riders.png" alt="Movistar Riders.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont eight-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-eight">
              <img src="./assets/paiN-Gaming.png" alt="paiN Gaming.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont nine-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-nine">
              <img src="./assets/Renegades.png" alt="Renegades.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont ten-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-ten">
              <img src="./assets/TYLOO.png" alt="GODSENT.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont eleven-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-eleven">
              <img src="./assets/GODSENT.png" alt="GODSENT.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twelve-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twelve">
              <img src="./assets/Sharks-Esports.png" alt="Sharks Esports.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont thirteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-thirteen">
              <img src="./assets/PGL-Major.png" alt="PGL Stoclholm Major 2021.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont fourteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-fourteen">
              <img src="./assets/Natus-Vincere.png" alt="Natus Vincere.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont fifteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-fifteen">
              <img src="./assets/G2-Esports.png" alt="G2 Esports.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont sixteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-sixteen">
              <img src="./assets/Gambit-Esports.png" alt="Gambit Esports.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont seventeen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-seventeen">
              <img src="./assets/Heroic.png" alt="Heroic.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont eighteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-eighteen">
              <img src="./assets/Team-Vitality.png" alt="Team Vitality.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont nineteen-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-nineteen">
              <img src="./assets/FURIA-Esports.png" alt="FURIA Esports.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twenty-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twenty">
              <img src="./assets/Virtus-pro.png" alt="Virtus Pro.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twentyone-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twentyone">
              <img src="./assets/Ninja-in-Pyjamas.png" alt="Ninja in Pyjamas.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twentytwo-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twentytwo">
              <img src="./assets/Entropiq.png" alt="Entropiq.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twentythree-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twentythree">
              <img src="./assets/Coppenhagen-Flames.png" alt="Coppenhagen Flames.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twentyfour-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twentyfour">
              <img src="./assets/FaZe-Clan.png" alt="FaZe Clan.png">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="container" class="bble-cont twentyfive-cont">
            <div id="bubble" class="bble-basic bble-twentyfive">
              <img src="./assets/Astralis.png" alt="Astralis.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button id="sldr-btn-after" class="sldr-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>

    </div>

  </header>

  <!-- Java Script -->
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In `exeC(fourteen, 13, 1, 1);` the last argument is `keyword`, that points to the second element in the array, it's value is 13.

Comment: @Teemu But he first does `fourteen--` to decrement it to `12`.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, but the index is not what OP needs, they've to pass `0`.

Comment: My bad there is a little error that I made, but I alr fix it. But another problem arise. @Barmar

Comment: My bad there is a little error that I made, but I alr fix it. But another problem arise. @Teemu

Comment: It might help, if you'd rename some of the variables. A variable named `fourteen` containing a value of 12 is a bit confusing, more meaningful variable names might help you to better follow the logic.

Comment: And can you get rid of all the code unrelated to the question? It's really hard to see what's going on here.

Comment: What is `contS`? Inside the function you're printing `i`, which is dependent on `contS.length`.

Comment: sorry if my question have many holes, but actually i was trying to make the code to be more efficient because before this one i got a code that actually work but really need me to manually input all the names one by one. @Teemu

Comment: i already update it to all of the remaining code @Barmar, also actually there will be `let one = 0;` to `let twenty-five = 24;`.

Comment: `contS.length` will always be `1`. An ID selector can only return one element, because IDs must be unique.

Comment: but when i pass `consolelog(contS.length);` it said 25. @Barmar

Comment: Can you add sample HTML?

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: i just knew that when you told me, thanks @Barmar.

Comment: You shouldn't have repeated `id="bubble"`. Use a class for repeated elements.

Comment: ok i will try it, thank you @Barmar